# Unexpected token error from node module import

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

I have a node app that uses the WebSocket lib ([`ws`](https://github.com/websockets/ws)) and I'm able to run this app on the local machine.

However, when I publish it to Azure App Service, I get the following error for the same code.

I've checked that both are running the same version of node 12.13.0, I've done `npm install` and the packages appear to be the same (they're also included when publishing anyways). And the error below is actually complaining about a file from the `ws` module.

The line of code that triggers this error is: `var WebSocket = require('ws');`

```
Wed Dec 04 2019 13:03:04 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time): Application has thrown an uncaught exception and is terminated:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\ws\index.js:3:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
Application has thrown an uncaught exception and is terminated:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\ws\index.js:3:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
```

Comment: Kindly post your code/efforts so that we can help you.

Comment: @PrabhjotSinghKainth I've added the code that leads to the error. I've no idea what is causing it so haven't tried anything. I've made sure node versions are same and packages are installed.

Comment: Did you set the node version using the "Use Node" step in Azure? Just asking to make 100% that you have the very same node version locally and on the server

Comment: @WojciechDynus I've set the node version by adding the `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION` key in application settings to be the same as on local machine and when I run `node -v` on the console and kudu console it does return the correct version. [As it show described in this post.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2016/04/20/nodejs-and-npm-versions-on-azure-app-services/). If by 'Use Node' Step you mean when created a new resource, then I created one from express template which is running on ASP.NET. I need web sockets enabled and that options is no in node stack web app.

Answer (score 0):

As reference, I tried to make the sample [`examples/server-stats/`](https://github.com/websockets/ws/tree/master/examples/server-stats) of GitHub repo [`websockets/ws`](https://github.com/websockets/ws) works on local and Azure App Service.

First, I downloaded its all source codes to my local machine and run `npm install` and `npm install ws` in my local directory, my local file structure as the figure below.

Fig 1. My local file structure of the sample `server-stats`.

[image]

Second, I tried to directly run it with the command `node index.js` and got an issue `Error: Cannot find module '../..'`, then I changed the file `index.js` for the code as below.

```
const WebSocket = require('ws'); // The original content is `require('../..')`
```

Then, I ran `node index.js` and open my browser to see the result, it works fine.

Fig 2. The `server-stats` works fine on local

[image]

As I known, Azure App Service requires the node app bind the port value from the code `process.env.PORT` and start up with a `web.config` file, so I changed the `index.js` file, and created a `web.config` file with the content comes from the Kudu wiki page [`Using a custom web.config for Node apps`](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Using-a-custom-web.config-for-Node-apps) and to use `index.js` instead of `server.js`, the codes as below.

- index.js

  ```
  const port =  8080;

  server.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('Listening on http://localhost:'+port);
  });
  ```
- web.config

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <!--
       This configuration file is required if iisnode is used to run node processes behind
       IIS or IIS Express.  For more information, visit:

       https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config
  -->

  <configuration>
    <system.webServer>
      <!-- Visit http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2013/11/14/introduction-to-websockets-on-windows-azure-web-sites.aspx for more information on WebSocket support -->
      <webSocket enabled="false" />
      <handlers>
        <!-- Indicates that the server.js file is a node.js site to be handled by the iisnode module -->
        <add name="iisnode" path="index.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
      </handlers>
      <rewrite>
        <rules>
          <!-- Do not interfere with requests for node-inspector debugging -->
          <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^index.js\/debug[\/]?" />
          </rule>

          <!-- First we consider whether the incoming URL matches a physical file in the /public folder -->
          <rule name="StaticContent">
            <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}"/>
          </rule>

          <!-- All other URLs are mapped to the node.js site entry point -->
          <rule name="DynamicContent">
            <conditions>
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.js"/>
          </rule>
        </rules>
      </rewrite>

      <!-- 'bin' directory has no special meaning in node.js and apps can be placed in it -->
      <security>
        <requestFiltering>
          <hiddenSegments>
            <remove segment="bin"/>
          </hiddenSegments>
        </requestFiltering>
      </security>

      <!-- Make sure error responses are left untouched -->
      <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />

      <!--
        You can control how Node is hosted within IIS using the following options:
          * watchedFiles: semi-colon separated list of files that will be watched for changes to restart the server
          * node_env: will be propagated to node as NODE_ENV environment variable
          * debuggingEnabled - controls whether the built-in debugger is enabled

        See https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config for a full list of options
      -->
      <!--<iisnode watchedFiles="web.config;*.js"/>-->
    </system.webServer>
  </configuration>
  ```

Then, I uploaded my all files and directoris to my Azure WebApp as the figure below to see in its Kudu Console.

Fig 3. The sample file structure on Azure WebApp via Kudu Console

[image]

After I added a new recode `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION` with `12.13.0` for `Application settings`,

Fig 4. Set the node runtime version via `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION` in `Application settings`

[image]

I opened it in browser, it did work.

Fig 5. For websocket feature with default settings, it doesn't work

[image]

There are two issues for the result above.

1. For a webapp using websocket, it's required to enable the feature `Web sockets` in the `General settings`.

   Fig 6. To enable the `Web sockets` feature in the `General settings`

   [image]
2. By default, Azure enabled SSL for HTTP accessing, so it's required to use `wss` instead of `ws` for websocket url in the `public/index.html` file.

   Fig 7. Use `wss` instead of `ws` in `public/index.html` for SSL enabled on Azure App Service.

   [image]

Finally, it works on Azure App Service.

[image]